# How to overcome Execessive Memory Footprint problem in Suitescript 1.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am getting this while trying to Yield.

> Failed to yield script (do-while), exiting: Reason =
> SS_EXCESSIVE_MEMORY_FOOTPRINT / Size = 1317509

Answer (score 1):

Read the Suitescipt 1.0 guide topic: **Understanding Memory Usage in Scheduled Scripts**

It includes a yellow box with:

> **Important**: Scripts that are resumed after an nlapiYieldScript() or
> nlapiSetRecoveryPoint() call will have their governance units reset.
> However, this does not reset the memory footprint of the script, which
> will continue to change until the script terminates. Therefore it is
> possible for the script to stay under the governance limit but exceed
> the memory size limit, at which point an SS_EXCESSIVE_MEMORY_FOOTPRINT
> error is thrown during the call to nlapiYieldScript() or
> nlapiSetRecoveryPoint().

The basic help offered in the topic besides an estimate of the memory consumed by each object type is:

> There are several useful techniques to reduce the memory overhead of
> scripts. Certain returned objects, for example nlobjRecord and
> nlobjSearchResult can be quite large. To reduce the memory consumed by
> these objects, convert them to native JavaScript objects and then
> operate on those objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

As an add on to Brian's answer I found that leaving a SearchResult around in a scheduled script would invariably result in some sort of error. So much so that I just made it a regular practice to put searches in a IIFE

generally:

```
var searchedResults = (function(){
    var accum = [];
    var results = nlapiSearchResults ...
    if(results){
        results.forEach(...) // push to accum or map or whatever your fancy
    }
    return accum;
})();
// and then process yield etc. 
simpleBatch(searchedResults, function(sr, idx){
    // do something with extracted result sr at index  idx
}, 200); // leave at 200 governance units after end of
```